# GPS information getting loss in video frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gps, processing, gopro

I have GoPro Hero6 black camera videos with GPS enabled. I want to get geotagged info of each frame, but when I convert video to frames using FFmPeg command "** ffmpeg -i GH012081.MP4 -vf fps=1 thumb%04d.jpg -hide_banner** " the GPS info got losses for each frame. How to retain GPS info in the frames?

After this, I have to sync the specific frame into the video for 2 or 3 seconds after drawing some 2d objects?

Answer (score 1):

When you execute this ffmpeg command you just extract the frames of the video to a sequence of jpeg files. You loose the Metadata (GPS, Axis, ...) as well as you loose the audio track for example. If you're interested in the Metadata information of your video files, you should take a look at these projects:

- [GoPro Metadata Format Parser](https://github.com/JuanIrache/gopro-utils) This is a set of command line tools to extract the Metdata
- [GPMF-parser](https://github.com/gopro/gpmf-parser) C Library to parse the Metadata programmatically